# Unfortunately process.com.android.phone has stopped unexpectedly error whenever i disconnect a call

Tags: applications

Instead of call duration and other details, i get "Unfortunately process.com.android.phone has stopped unexpectedly error" whenever i disconnect a call. I am not able to check the prepaid balance of my phone. No USSD code works properly. This is happening in my new LetV 1s phone.

I have cleared the cache mentioned in the sites as a resolution. I even did a factory reset. Still it is not working. 
Kindly help me in this regard.

Thanks and Regards, 
Veena

Answer (score -1):

Try clearing data of

- Phone (com.anddroid.server.telecom)
- In-call Interface (com.android.incallui)
- Dialer (com.android.dialer)

You could temporarily download TrueDialer or any other 3rd party Dialer.

If possible a provide a logcat.

Comment: Can you explain why clearing data of those particular apps would work even when factory reset (which already clears data of all the apps) didn't help?

Comment: Assuming the dialer crashes because of a bug, the best course of action would be to clear its data and install a 3rd party app. Since those 3 apps manage calling, USSD etc. wiping their data would make sure the crash did not leave bad data.